# Using a generic class with a generic class

Tags: java, class, object, generics

I got a class (from akka) which looks like this:
`public class HighLevelEventBus extends ScanningEventBus<Class<? extends TimedEvent>, Integer, String> {...}`
What I want to do is turn this from `Class<? extends TimedEvent>` to some kind of Object, like `<T extends TimedEvent>` for example. The reason why I want to do this is because in ScanningEventBus there are some methods like

```
@Override
    public boolean matches(String classifier, Class<? extends TimedEvent> event) {
        return nuull;
    }
```

Inside this Method I want to do something like `event.someMethodFromTimedEvent()` but I have to do this before: `TimedEvent timedEvent = event.cast(event.getClass()); timedEvent.someMethodFromTimedEvent();` which seems wrong to me.

My goal is to have something similar to this method:

```
public <T extends TimedEvent> boolean matches(String somethingSomething, T event) {
        return classifier.equals(event.someMethodFromTimedEvent());
    }
```

but I need to Override the original `matches(...)` Method, so in order to do that I need to change the `ScanningEventBus<Class<? extends TimedEvent>, Integer, String> {...}`

Comment: Now what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala there is no real issue, I am able to solve my problem, but my solution is ugly in my opinion. I want to know if there is a way to substitute `Class<? extends TimedEvent>` for `<T extends TimedEvent>` in the ScanningEventBus